# Multiple solutions for trig function with period

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Find all angles with limits $−\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$ which satisfy $\sin 4 \theta = 1$

The working out is given as:

If $\sin 4 \theta = 1$ then $4 \theta = \pi/2 + 2 k \pi$, so $\theta = \pi/8 + k \pi/2$
For $−\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$ we have $\theta = \pi/8, 5 \pi/8, −3 \pi/8, −7\pi/8$

How did they find the other values of $5 \pi/8, −3 \pi/8$ and $−7 \pi/8$?

Was it just using the unit circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative approach:

You have that $4\theta$ must be congruent to $\pi/2$, within a modulus of $(2\pi).$

So, form the following sequence

- $4\theta = \pi/2 \implies $ 
  $\theta = \pi/8.$
- $4\theta = 2\pi + \pi/2 = 5\pi/2 \implies $  
  $\theta = 5\pi/8.$
- $4\theta = 9\pi/2\implies $  
  $\theta = 9\pi/8.$
- $4\theta = (13)\pi/2\implies $  
  $\theta = (13)\pi/8.$
- $4\theta = (17)\pi/2\implies $  
  $\theta = (17)\pi/8.$
- $4\theta = (21)\pi/2\implies $  
  $\theta = (21)\pi/8.$
- $\cdots$

At this point, you stop and take stock:

the candidate values for distinct solutions are the elements in the following set:

$$\left\{~\frac{\pi}{8}, ~\frac{5\pi}{8}, ~\frac{9\pi}{8}, ~\frac{13\pi}{8}, ~\frac{17\pi}{8}, ~\frac{21\pi}{8}, \cdots ~\right\}. \tag1 $$

Now, you (again) stop and consider.

If you examine the values in (1) above, considering that you are only interested in values that are distinct, with respect to a modulus of $(2\pi)$, you realize that

$$\frac{\pi}{8} \equiv \frac{17\pi}{8} \pmod{2\pi}, ~~~\frac{5\pi}{8} \equiv \frac{21\pi}{8} \pmod{2\pi}. \tag2 $$

Further, you should also realize at this time, that the ongoing pattern will recur.  That is, you should realize that the following infinite sequence of angles

$$\frac{25\pi}{8}, ~\frac{29\pi}{8},  ~\frac{33\pi}{8},  ~\frac{37\pi}{8}, \cdots $$

will not be yielding any distinct angles, with respect to the $(2\pi)$ modulus.

Therefore, you realize that there are only $(4)$ distinct solutions, within a modulus of $(2\pi)$.  These solutions are given by the set

$$\left\{~\frac{\pi}{8}, ~\frac{5\pi}{8}, ~\frac{9\pi}{8}, ~\frac{13\pi}{8} ~\right\}. \tag3 $$

At this point, you are close to your goal.

(3) above represents all distinct satisfying values $\theta$ such that $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi.$

However, this isn't good enough.  The problem requires you to identify all distinct values $\theta$ such that $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi.$

If you examine (3) above, you realize that the first two values (from the left) are okay, but that the next two values need adjustment.  What this means is that the two values of $~\dfrac{9\pi}{8}~$ and $~\dfrac{13\pi}{8}~$ need to be adjusted.

The adjustment needed is that these two values must be re-expressed in their modulus $(2\pi)$ equivalents that are within the range $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi.$

The easiest way to do this is to subtract $(2\pi)$ from each of the two *out of range* angles.

So:

- $\dfrac{9\pi}{8} - 2\pi = \dfrac{-7\pi}{8}.$
- $\dfrac{13\pi}{8} - 2\pi = \dfrac{-3\pi}{8}.$

Therefore, the refined expression of the 4 distinct solutions, from (3) above, are expressed as

$$\left\{~\frac{\pi}{8}, ~\frac{5\pi}{8}, ~\frac{-7\pi}{8}, ~\frac{-3\pi}{8} ~\right\}. \tag4 $$

Comment: Thankyou so much

Answer (score 2):

When you reach at:  $θ=\displaystyle \frac {\pi} 8 +\frac{k \pi} 2 ,k\in\mathbb{Z}\text{ } (1) $
We are given that:  $θ\in[-\pi, \pi] \text{ } (2)$
So:  $(1),(2)\implies -\pi<\displaystyle \frac {\pi} 8 +\frac{k \pi} 2<\pi\iff -\frac {\pi} 8-\pi<\frac{k \pi} 2< -\frac {\pi} 8+\pi\iff $
$$ \displaystyle -\frac {9\pi} 8<\frac{k \pi} 2<\frac {7\pi} 8 \iff -\frac {9\pi} 4<{k \pi} <\frac {7\pi} 4 \iff -\frac{9} 4<{k } <\frac {7} 4$$ But, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$  so we have to find all the $k$ that belong to:  $\begin{bmatrix}\displaystyle-\frac{9} 4,\frac {7} 4 \end{bmatrix}$  such as:  $k\in \mathbb{Z}. $
After you find the $k$ replace it to the equation $(1)$ and you find all the $θ$ 
So all the possible $k$ that meet our conditions are:  $k=-2,-1,0,1$
So we conclude that, all the possible solutions are:
$$ \begin{Bmatrix}\displaystyle -\frac {7\pi} 8 ,-\frac {3\pi} 8,\frac {\pi} 8 ,\frac {5\pi} 8\end{Bmatrix}$$

Comment: This is the logical conclusion of the method in the question. For this particular problem, there are so few solutions that one can try them one by one. First $\pi/8$: a solution. Add $\pi/2$; we get $5\pi/8,$ also a solution. Add $\pi/2$ again; too great. So try subtracting from $\pi/8$ instead; once gives you $-3\pi/8$, twice gives you $-7\pi/8$; the third time goes too far, so there are no more solutions.

Comment: @DavidK However we have to mention that because the problem is simple it's easy to find other ways to calculate all the possible solutions.If the range was a little bit more complicated, i think my solution is the easiest and perhaps the fastest method.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. This answer is of course completely correct and moreover there are many variations of the problem where it is really helpful to use all of the methods used here.

Comment: Typesetting tip:  Type `$x \in S$` to obtain $x \in S$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the tip.Post has been edited :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the plot of $\sin(4 \theta)$.  Does this help you?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the equality $\theta=\frac\pi8+\frac{k\pi}2$:

- if $k=1$, you get $\frac{5\pi}8$;
- if $k=-1$, you get $-\frac{3\pi}8$;
- if $k=-2$, you get $-\frac{7\pi}8$.

Comment: how do you know to use the numbers 1, -1 and -2?

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking, for instance, how do I know that $\frac\pi8+\frac{1\times\pi}2=\frac{5\pi}8$?

Comment: Yes exactly, like how do you know specifically to use those numbers, K could be any number's couldnt it? How do you know to use 1, -1 and -2 to get the correct answers?

Comment: Because if I use an other integer greater than $1$, then I will get a $\theta$ greater than $\pi$, and if I use any other integer smaller than $-2$, then I will get a $\theta$ smaller than $-\pi$.

Comment: ah okay I get it now, so if I had a question that was say, π/8+kπ2 but the limits where 0≤θ≤2π, my greatest limit to not max out over $2π$ would be k=3 which gives 5.10?

Comment: @ConstantinosPisimisis I have done, thankyou

Comment: @AlynaKuteaeyva Ironically you accepted as best solution the most "complicated" i think.Nevermind.If you have any other quesiton don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Yes, if you were interested in solutions from the interval $[0,2\pi]$, you would have to take into account other values of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be rewritten as:

> Solve the equation for the angle $\theta$, that satisfies $$\sin(4\theta)=1$$ with $−\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$

At first, solving the equation gives:
$$\arcsin(4x) = \arcsin(1)$$
$$4x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\cdot2\pi$$
$$x=\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{k\pi}{2}$$

Of the part where we put $k2\pi$ into it, remember that by adding any number $k$, that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (Whole number, if you may wonder), it is the same act as rotating the point on a circle $360^{\circ}$, and go back to the same position. Now considering that the value limit which was given is $−\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$. First, solve for half of the region we are bounded, $\pi \leq \theta \leq 0$, with the solution, $x=\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{k\pi}{2}$, you may realize that you have to make the angle $\theta$ stay inside the region, which correlates with the I and II quadrant.

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image]

Thus, as you might see, the number $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be such value like 1 for the angle to stay inside the boundaries. For example, with $k = 1 $ , the angle $\theta$ is:
$$\theta = \frac{5\pi}{8}$$ which stays inside the I and II quadrant.

For the negative, or the other half, remember that negative angles start counter-clockwise from the starting point, that is, now it is all angles stay inside the III and IV quadrant, accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \cos 4 \theta = \sqrt{1-\sin^2 4 \theta }=0 $$

$$ \theta = (2k-1) \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{4} $$

so the first halt of radius vector is at the principal value $+\dfrac{\pi}{8}$ and next it continues around the origin halting at  multiples of $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ along a unit circle either in the clockwise or in the anti- clockwise direction.

[image]